# TryParse SSIS Ignore Source Row

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, etl, derived-column

I have a serialized code, and from within this code there are numeric values which when parsed represent a date.

```
For example, 011756420176654 
*Note* array index may be off
Substring(1,2) = 01
Substring(3,2) = 17
```

I'm trying to ignore the row, without replacing the original row. I have a derived column, and am doing this in the column.

```
(dt_date)(Substring([My Code], 1, 2) + "-" + Substring([My Code], 3, 2) + (dt_str,10,1252)datepart("year",getdate()))
```

My intention here is to configure my error output to ignore the [My Code] field if the "TryParse"-logic in the derived column fails. I know if I were passing the derived column, that selecting ignore on the configuration will pass null, but the problem is I'm trying to (on error) ignore the source row and pass that as null (ie [My Code]).

Once this hit's the database, another process consumes it and attempts to parse the dates. It will not fail on null values, so I want to validate that essentially "is date"-logic before allowing the record through, or setting it to null.

Edit: Per Keith's solution, I came to this. I was having issues accessing the output buffer, but after some MSDN on syntax I came up with the following which works perfectly.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        DateTime dateValue;
        string test = Row.ReceiptCode.Substring(0, 2) + "/" + Row.ReceiptCode.Substring(2, 2) + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

        if (DateTime.TryParse(test, out dateValue) && Row.ReceiptCode.Length ==16)
    {

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();

        Output0Buffer.EndDate = Row.EndDate;
        Output0Buffer.Q10 = Row.Q10;
        Output0Buffer.Q8 = Row.Q8;

        Output0Buffer.ValidatedReceipt = Row.ReceiptCode;
    }
    else 
    {
        Output1Buffer.AddRow();

        Output1Buffer.EndDate = Row.EndDate;
        Output1Buffer.Q10 = Row.Q10;
        Output1Buffer.Q8 = Row.Q8;
        Output1Buffer.Error = Row.ReceiptCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: this smells of a script component vs a derived column

Comment: Yes, definitely closer to what I am looking for.

Comment: You just missed the second date separator !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a script transformation:

Add an ouput column (convDate) and check [My Code] as read:

Here's your code:

```
string test = Row.[My Code].Substring(1,2) + "/" + Row.[My Code].Substring(3,2)+"/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

if (DateTime.TryParse(test, out dateValue))
{Row.convDate = dateValue;  }
```

Comment: within the script task, I assume this should go in the Input0Buffer overrride.. This exposes the input (Row.[My Code] as above) and allows me to parse the input to a datetime variable. How then do I output to the convDate? Do I need to do something like Row.CreateNewOutPutRows(convDate)? That doesn't seem to make sense as I configured the output row in my setup. 
Inputs & Outputs -> Output 0 -> Output Columns -> convDate
I cannot see this from within script component.

Comment: The code has all the c# you need. however, you are gtting hung up in the SSIS GUI.  On input/output tab select [My Code] for read. Also, on output add a new column to Output 0 called convDate. This will let you access the two columns from the Row

Comment: Found answer.. Output0Buffer.convDate = dateValue;

Comment: I don't agree with using Script component while you can achieve that in derived column **(especially when implementing very simple logic)**, the error was simple the OP forgot to add a separator between month and year. also he didn't arrange the datepart in `yyyy_MM-dd` format.

Answer (score 2):

**It is better *(from performance perspective)* to avoid using Script Component while using simple expression**

- [SSIS component vs C# script performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857128/ssis-component-vs-c-sharp-script-performance)

The problem that you have in you derived column expression is that you are missing the second dash `-` and specify`50` as length of string, try using the following expression:

```
(dt_date)(Substring([My Code], 1, 2) + "-" + Substring([My Code], 3, 2) + "-" +  (dt_str,50,1252)datepart("year",getdate()))
```

Also it is preferable to use the universal date formatting `YYYY-MM-DD` while handling date values:

```
(dt_date)((dt_str,50,1252)datepart("yy",getdate()) + "-" + Substring([My Code], 3, 2) + "-" + Substring([My Code], 1, 2))
```

Make sure you have configured the error output to ignore failure:

[image]

---

## Update 1

If you need to return the original string value use the following expression:

```
((dt_date)((dt_str,50,1252)datepart("yy",getdate()) + "-" + Substring([My Code], 3, 2) + "-" + Substring([My Code], 1, 2)) == (dt_date)((dt_str,50,1252)datepart("yy",getdate()) + "-" + Substring([My Code], 3, 2) + "-" + Substring([My Code], 1, 2))) 
? [My Code] 
: NULL(dt_str,50,1252)
```

Comment: Ok. I agree this works but it kills me to chase errors on properties in gui

Comment: @KeithL in this case the OP needs to implement a tryparse logic which doesn't raise error on parsing failure

Comment: Agree. Both work. With mine. It attempts to parse. If fail writes nothing hence leaves column null. To me. Fixing 2 lines of code is easier than finding a property.

Comment: @KeithL as you said both works. To be fair you will get my upvote :)

Comment: I'm not arguing you are wrong. Just a preference for me when I have 100s of packages to maintain.

Comment: @KeithL implementing custom code is not preferable when it can be achieved by ssis component

Comment: Ditto ditto ditto

Comment: I'm on the fence :3 For version migration and maintainability, I'd rather keep to basic SSIS components, but I'm not sure I can (and I do prefer C#). What I need to do is do the TryParse, but do something completely different if it's valid. The code is a string of numbers (a receipt) and from that there is a date parsed. I am trying to clean it before it gets into my stage table and SQL tries to parse it blowing me up. We ignore null, so the original column would just be passed null on error. This only allows me to pass the failed column right?

Comment: @alykins if date is parsed successfully  then the value is passed else a null value is passed

Comment: But that's what I mean, I want to validate the parse, but then pass the serialized string un-parsed (knowing it will parse later). Essentially cleaning data from source. I have it going through a C# script task where I am able to make a validation class.. My biggest obstacle was understanding the syntax for the output buffer (figured out*). This solution does work great if I wanted to parse in the derived column; thank you for other concepts.

Comment: @alykins it can be done with derived column. I will edit my answer in a while